# Ignore sign of numbers with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have the following df:

```
gene = c("a", "b", "c", "d")
fc = c(-1, -2, 1, 2)
df = data.frame(gene, fc)
```

I am using the following code for plotting:

```
ggplot(df, aes(gene, fc)) + geom_point(size=df$fc) + theme_minimal()
```

How can I ignore the sign of the values in "fc" while plotting?

Thanks

Comment: Do you just want `geom_point(aes(size=abs(fc))`? `abs()` takes the absolute value of numbers (it drops the negative sign).

Comment: Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the absolute value function `abs()` to ignore the negative sign. For example

```
ggplot(df, aes(gene, fc)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=abs(fc))) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

Just make sure to put properties that you want to map to data inside `aes()` at all times. Rarely should you ever see a `$` in ggplot code.